# What is an open subset of $X$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

From Walter Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* Ed. 3.

> **2.29 Remark** Suppose $E \subset Y \subset X$ where $X$ is a metric space. To say that $E$ is an open subset of $X$ means that to each point $p \in E$ there is associated a positive number $r$ such that the conditions $d(p,q) < r$, $q \in X$ imply that $q \in E$.

My understanding is that $E$ is an open subset of $X$ if for all $p \in E$, there exists $r > 0$ such that all $q \in X$ with $d(p, q) < r$ is in $E$. That is to say, every $p \in E$ has a neighborhood containing only elements of $X$ that's also in $E$.

Is this equivalent to remark 2.29?

Why state "$q \in X$ imply that $q \in E$" instead of just "$q \in E$"?

"$q \in X$ imply that $q \in E$" is true if $q \notin X$ and $q \notin E$, so the conditions are satisfied if $d(p, q) < r \wedge q \notin X \wedge q \notin E$, but this seems irrelevant when mentioning subsets of $X$.

Comment: Please do not use images to convey key information about the post. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742) for an explanation why. This is a very short excerpt, and you can easily type it; please do so.

Comment: My question is why is $Y$ even there? I think that perhaps what had been intended was **2.29 Remark** Suppose $E \subset Y \subset X$ where $X$ is a metric space. To say that $E$ is an open subset of $Y$ means that to each point $p \in E$ there is associated a positive number $r$ such that the conditions $d(p,q) < r$, $q \in Y$ imply that $q \in E$.

Comment: Note that the verb there is "imply", not "implies"---it is the third person *plural* conjugation.  There are two conditions which, together, imply the conclusion.  If Rudin were to simply state "$d(p,q) < r$ implies $q\in E$", then it leaves the question "Where does $q$ live?"  The sentence might more readily be rendered as "...the condition $d(p,q) < r$ where $q\in X$ implies that $q\in E$."

Comment: But, as @robjohn states, I am also confused by the inclusion of $Y$, and wonder if something is missing here...

Comment: I have found the relevant material, and the truncation of the comment causes confusion, here.  In this comment, Rudin is explaining the difference between an open set, and a *relatively* open set.  The comment continues:  "But we have already observed (Sec. 2.16) that $Y$ is also a metric space, so that our definitions may equally well be made within $Y$.  To be quite explicit, let us say that $E$ is *open relative to $Y$* if to each $p\in E$ there is associated an $r > 0$ such that $q\in E$ whenever $d(p,q)<r$ and $q\in Y$...

Comment: "...Example 2.21(g) showed that a set may be open relative to $Y$ without being an open subset of $X$.  However, there is a simple relation between these concepts, which we now state."  (Rudin then continues with Theorem 2.30).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly equivalent, Rudin is basically saying that if you are closer to $p$ than that particular radius *and* you are a point of $X$, then it means you are in $E$: in easier terms, it means that for every point in the open set you can always find an open ball of some tiny radius such that this ball is all contained in $E$.

Your last condition $d(p, q) < r \wedge q \notin X \wedge q \notin E$ seemes a bit a contradiction to me. No point can satisfy both the first and the second condition.

Comment: Let $X$ be the open interval $(1, 3)$ and $E$ be (1, 2). Choose $p = 1.01$, $q = 0.99$, $r = 0.5$. Then $d(p, q) < r \wedge q \notin X \wedge q \notin E$, but $E$ is an open subset of $X$.

Comment: I see your point, but you are implicitly supposing to work in $\mathbb{R}$, and that $X \subset \mathbb{R}$. Otherwise, you could not even define $d(p,q)$ since $q$ is not in $X$. Here the concept of subspace topology comes into place, but it is more technical than this.

Comment: I see. We are using $d(p, q)$ as defined on $X$ since we say "$E$ is an open subset of $X$". If we say "$E$ is an open subset of $K$", then we use $d(p, q)$ defined on $K$.